# Making a transparent play button icon like the one on the airbnb website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to make a website with a looping video inside a div like on this website : https://www.airbnb.com/?af=43720035&c=A_TC%3D5deb8yxasn%26G_MT%3De%26G_CR%3D89719542383%26G_N%3Dg%26G_K%3Dairbnb%26G_P%3D%26G_D%3Dc&gclid=CKDKlI7rx84CFaYy0wodFLQBCg&dclid=CN3MsY7rx84CFaox0wodEZEGFg

It's going well but I'm not sure how to create the play button in the middle, transparency and all? Not so much the javascript and functionality but just the button itself, anyone know what would be the wisest route to making one? Thanks

Comment: Can you add your attempt, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an icon to me, maybe try something like font awesome. Then style it the way you want with CSS (color, opacity, etc.) http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Answer (score 0):

Your link no longer works, so, it's an educated guess as to what you want, but here's code for creating a transparent play button.

```
.transparentPlayButton {
    width:120px; height:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

.transparentPlayButton:before,
.transparentPlayButton:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;    
}

.transparentPlayButton:before{   
    top:20px; left:40px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 40px solid black;
    border-bottom: 40px solid black;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9999px #000;
    z-index:-1;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.transparentPlayButton:hover:before {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9999px #cc3333;
    border-top: 40px solid #cc3333;
    border-bottom: 40px solid #cc3333;
}

.transparentPlayButton:after{
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MastaBaba/bo9g4jfz/).